# maven pom.xml file wont recognize jersey framework

Tags: java, xml, maven, intellij-idea

I am trying to import jersey using maven central but, intellij wont read my pom.xml dependency for jersey.  The version # shows in red with the following error:

[image]

here is the pom.xml textually:

```
     <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example.emanuel</groupId>
  <artifactId>jerseyexample</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>jerseyexample Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
      <version>2.19</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>jerseyexample</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <server>TomcatServer</server>
          <path>/newjersey</path>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

i copied the dependency straight from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-client/2.19)

Answer (score 0):

the issue was with my settings.xml file that maven uses to build the project.  I had a mirror defined in there that used a proxy and it was blocking the download.